# Searching messages using regex - gmail api

Tags: php, api, gmail-api

I am looking at building a small web application which looks for emails which contain serial keys/codes in an email. I have tried searching around but not sure if Gmail API accepts searching in messages using REGEX.

Anyone got any ideas or used it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gmail API search has the [**same features the Gmail client has**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering), which is [**documented here**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en). It has no support for regex, sadly.

Comment: That is a shame! I might have to just fetch the emails using the API and then use php to find what I want then. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to search with keywords rather regex. Gmail doesnt support regex based search.

Example:- subject:dinner Words in the subject line

Example:- "dinner and movie tonight"  Search for an exact word or phrase